# How to generate unique request in CURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have one script which fetch data using Curl in multiple request at a same time with same URL.

Is there any configuration in CURL to each time sending like new request ?

Because second time when ever I tried its behave like fake request using CURL.

Currently i am using this configuration.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 150);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );            
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

If any one have any suggestion then please help me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you want another curl request just create a new curl object again.

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();
...
curl_close($ch1);
curl_close($ch2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same options on every curl request, you can use curl_exec in a loop without closing or re initializing it :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 150);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );            
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
foreach($urls as $url ){
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $data = curl_exec($ch); 
}
curl_close($ch);
```